# Sort strings in a data frame in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

How can I sort in an ascending way the elements of a column inside a data frame?

For example, I have:

table<-data.frame(col1=c("w d f", "g t y", "c d a", "o w q"))

```
   col1
   w d f
   g t y
   c d a
   o w q
```

and I want

```
   col1
   d f w
   g t y
   a d c
   o q w
```

Comment: I think the third element would be `a c d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We split the 'col1' by space into a `list`, `sort` the elements by looping through the elements (`sapply`) and `paste` it together

```
table$col1 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(table$col1), ' '), 
                        function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=' '))
table$col1
#[1] "d f w" "g t y" "a c d" "o q w"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort_c <- function(x){
  strsplit(as.character(x),"") %>% unlist() %>% sort() %>% str_c(collapse="")
}

apply(table,1,sort_social_q) %>% as.data.frame()
```

output:
1   dfw
2   gty
3   acd
4   oqw